# How to display values of 2 different lists in 2 different columns in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have 2 lists in my Flask App, I want to display the values of both lists in this manner

```
Score | Remark 
5     | Excellent
2     | Poor
3     | Satisfactory
```

And this the route in my app.py file

```
def remarks():
    remarks=[]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        score = list(map(float,(request.form['scores']).split()))
        for i in range(len(score)):
            if(score[i]>=4):
                remarks.append("Excellent")
            elif(score[i]==3):
                remarks.append("Satisfactory")
            else:
                remarks.append("Poor")
        return render_template('results.html', score=score, remarks=remarks)
```

This is my results.html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h3>Here is your report</h3>

{% for s in score %}
    <h1>{{s}}</h1>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

How do I display the remarks list besides every score in my results.html file?

Comment: create pandas data frame using them and then do `.to_html` . pass that to frontend.

Comment: Thank You, @Pygirl. It worked

Answer (score 1):

You can zip both score and remarks in flask . then you loop over them in front end table

just to declare it:
edit the last line of (python) return:

```
score_remarks = zip(score, remarks)
return render_template('results.html',sr=score_remarks)
```

and the front-end will look like that:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Score</th>
    <th>Remark</th>
</tr>

    {% for s in sr %}
    <tr>    
    <td>{{s[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{s[1]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

</table>
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing an example.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary instead of an array and render it directly as key-value.

In your app.py do this :

```
def remarks():
    score_remark_dict = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        score = list(map(float, (request.form['scores']).split()))
        for i in range(len(score)):
            if score[i] >= 4:
                score_remark_dict[score[i]] = 'Excellent'
            elif score[i] == 3:
                score_remark_dict[score[i]] = 'Satisfactory'
            else:
                score_remark_dict[score[i]] = "Poor"

        return render_template('results.html', score_remark_dict=score_remark_dict)
```

In your HTML do this :

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

 {% block content %}

<h3> Here is your report </h3>
<h1> Score |  Remark </h1>
{% for s in score_remark_dict %}
    {{ s }} |  {{ score_remark_dict[s] }}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```